# Why function default parameters cannot be perferct forwarded in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I found quite weird behavior from my perspective: function default arguments cannot be forwarded in code bellow.

```
void Test(int test = int{}) {}

template<typename F, typename ...Args>
void Foo(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    Foo(Test, 0); // This compiles
    Foo(Test);    // This doesn't compile
}
```

Clang reports:
error: too few arguments to function call, expected 1, have 0
GCC and VC report same errors.

Can anybody explain it?

Code is here:
http://rextester.com/live/JOCY22484

Comment: Shorter test case: `auto f = Test; f();`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Test` is a function that always takes one argument. If its declaration with the default argument is visible when `Test` is invoked by name, the compiler will implicitly add the default argument to the call. However, once `Test` has been converted into a pointer or reference to function, the default argument information is no longer visible.

This can be worked around by creating a functor which really does take zero or one arguments and has that information encoded into its type so it cannot be destroyed, like so:

```
struct Test {
    void operator()(int) { /* ... */ }
    void operator()() { operator(int{}); }
} test;
// ...
Foo(test, 0); // ok
Foo(test);    // ok
```

Comment: `void operator()(int = 0) { /* ... */ }` will work just fine.